# Session based service bus with Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am using session queue on Azure and when I push some data on queue,I write one Azure function to trigger.

Please note that I have created statefull/session based queue.

The problem is when I push data to queue at that moment I got error like

> The listener for function 'xxx' was unable to start.
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus: It is not possible for an entity that requires
>   sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver

So my question is am I not able to use function with queue/topic with session?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update 2020:

Set [`isSessionsEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration) property in your `function.json`.

<strike>This is a common ask, but currently Web Jobs SDK, and thus Azure Functions, don't support Service Bus sessions. See [WebJobs SDK issue](https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/529); unfortunately there's no progress 3 years after it was created. Add a +1 in [Azure Functions issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/563).</strike>

Comment: As @alessio has pointed out this is now possible as written in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration) by setting the `isSessionsEnabled = true`. This answer was correct at the time, but should be no longer be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 5):

I think its actually possible now, using the beta package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/3.1.0-beta2`.

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("core-test-queue1-sessions",
    Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus",
    IsSessionsEnabled = true)]string myQueueItem, 
    IMessageSession messageSession,
    ILogger log)
```

Also you can specify new SessionHandlerOptions section in host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "SessionHandlerOptions":
             {
                "MaxAutoRenewDuration": "00:01:00",
                "MessageWaitTimeout": "00:05:00",
                "MaxConcurrentSessions": 16,
                "AutoComplete": true,
             }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/529#issuecomment-491113458

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify in function.json of consumer AF a property "IsSessionsEnabled": true